# Push multiple view controllers in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have three controllers (FriendVC, ChatVC, PrivateChatVC) inside storyboad, and navigation is sequential :

A user can navigate from `FriendVC` to `ChatVC`(in `TabBarController`), and then to `PrivateChatVC`.

Now, I need to make some button that will open `PrivateChatVC` from `FriendVC` but will also put `ChatVC` on navigation stack, so when a user will press back from `PrivateChatVC` he will be returned to `ChatVC`.

Problem I'm facing is that my `ChatVC` is a `TabBarController`.

Below is the code I'm trying:

```
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
   PrivateChatController * privateChatController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"privatechat"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:privateChatController animated:YES];
```

I'm assuming that `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]` will load the tabbar and then `[self.navigationController pushViewController:privateChatController animated:YES];` will load `PrivateChatVC`.

However, it only takes me to `ChatVC` and `PrivateChatVC` never loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, you need to select the ChatVC tab as you've done, but use a singleton class and set a param so that when ChatVC becomes the active VC it knows to immediately push PrivateChatVC.

In FriendVC:

```
_singleton.showPrivateChat = YES;
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; // select ChatVC tab
```

In ChatVC:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear {

    if (_singleton.showPrivateChat) {
        PrivateChatController * privateChatController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"privatechat"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:privateChatController animated:YES]; 
        _singleton.showPrivateChat = NO; // reset boolean
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Warning!! This is very bad code! Use it at your own risk :)

```
ChatVC *chatVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chat"];
PrivateChatController * privateChatController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"privatechat"];  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:privateChatController animated:YES];
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[viewControllers insertObject:chatVC atIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```